# CSS files with random number not found under Ubuntu

Tags: css, apache, ubuntu

Recently I set up a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 + LAMP.

In a web application I've found that the frontend was not displayed correctly. So I checked in Chrome browser Developer Tools, and find that most of the css files were missing.

These css files are named with random numbers, for instance, *Resources/Public/Css/Basic.1536323070.css*.

But actually in the folder *Resources/Public/Css/* there exists only a file named *Basic.css*. Therefore the system could not find the *Basic.1536323070.css*, and the frontend was not shown properly.

In Contrast, I've checked this in another PC (also with Ubuntu 16.04 + LAMP) of mine. In this PC, the css files like *Resources/Public/Css/Basic.1546357210.css* can be found by the system (although in the corresponding folder there is only the file *Basic.css*), so, the frontend is well shown.

On these two PCs I've used the same version of Apache, Mysql, PHP, and done the identical configurations.

Can someone tell me why one PC can find the css files with random numbers, but another can't?

Comment: It sounds like some files have been "minified" on one server but not on the other.

Comment: I've found the reason. It relates to Apache rewrite. After I enabled this function, the requested resources were found :)

Comment: These numbers are sometimes used to force browsers to download new versions of files, and not keep the ones they have in cache.  You can increment the number every time you change the code, thus the browser will think it is a new file.